# Setting a Style for a popUpWindow

Tags: android, android-activity, styles, themes, popupwindow

I'm working on an app that requires something along the lines of a pop up window. I have two different designs I'm considering. One where the popUpWindow opens as a normal popUpWindow with out starting a new activity and another design where the pop up opens as a new activity. In the latter design (where a new activity is open) I can make the new window look really nice by putting the following line in the activity tag of the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

However it seems that starting a new activity is not going to work for my overall design. My question is how can I apply this "Dialog" style to a regular popUpWindow?

Below is the code where I instantiate and show the popUpWindow:

```
PopupWindow popUpWindow;
popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpView, 250, 325, true);
popUpWindow.showAtLocation(mainLinearLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
```

Comment: I've added the code dealing with the popUpWindow, is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing which achieved what I wanted:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    popUpLayout = Globals.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_layout,
            null);
    dialog.setContentView(popUpLayout);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(275, 350);
    dialog.show();
```